# Is there anything missing in this proof?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, proof-without-words

I came with this geometry problem and numerous lengthy solutions were proposed, so I thought there must be something missing in my solution.

**The problem:** Given that $\angle CAB=3x$, $\angle BCA=x$, and $\angle BDA=45$, determine the value of $x$.

[image]

And here is my sort of proof-without-words type of solution. (Thus $\angle x = 22.5$.)

[image]

Okay. Does adding this line clarify it? $\angle ABD=\beta$ and $\angle DBC=\alpha$. Then, $3x+\beta = 135$ and $\alpha + x=45$, thus $\beta=3\alpha$.

Comment: I don't understand, how, do you know that one angle at B is 3x and other x? that is true only iff BD = AC/2

Comment: @Maria That is given in the question.

Comment: What is given ?

Comment: How have you proved that $\angle ABD=\angle DAB$?

Answer (score 1):

The key is to consider the point $X$ on $BC$ such that $AX=CX$. Then $\angle CAX = \angle XCA = x$, hence 
$$\angle BXA = \angle XCA + \angle CAX = x + x = 2x = 3x - x = \angle CAB - \angle CAX = \angle XAB.$$
Hence $AB=BX$.

[image]

Also, 
$$\angle XDB = 90^\circ - \angle BDA = 90^\circ - 45^\circ = 45^\circ = \angle BDA.$$

Using the well-known fact that the angle bisector and perpendicular bisector intersect at a point on the circumcircle, we get that $X,D,A,B$ lie on a circle. Hence 
$$2x = \angle BXA = \angle BDA = 45^\circ,$$
so $x = 22.5^\circ$.

Comment: Well done +1......

Answer (score 0):

The proof requires $\angle ACB = 90^0$.

Here is an indirect method of verifying that x is equal to $22.5^0$ (instead of giving a wild guess).

1) Create the semi-circle AXB (center = D, radius = DB) as shown.

2) Locate C’ on the circumference such that $\angle ADC’ = 45^0$.

3) Join BC’ such that $\angle DBC’ = y$. Then, $y = … = 22.5^0$.

It should be clear that, $z = … = 67.5^0$, which happens to be 3 times of y.

After mapping back with C’ = C, y = x, etc., we can say that x = 22.5 is one of the possible solution(s).

[image]

At a glance there is another location for C (which is $C_1$) provided $\theta = 3 \phi$. By moving $C_1$ along DC (and extended), geogebra shows such relation is not possible.